# Accessing session's attribute from jsp fails

Tags: jsp, struts2

Actually, when I use scriplets: `<%= session.getAttribute("loginId") %>` the value is printed on page . The problem arises when I use Expression Language, then it doesn't show anything.

```
<td>LoginId: </td>
<td><input type="text" value="${loginId}" /></td>
```

Comment: `username` is it a member in action class to holds the `loginid`.

Comment: @Satya I edited my code because I had typed it incorrectly while posting, but the problem persists.

Comment: Its `${session.loginId}`.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: it's not JSP, just plain HTML

Comment: `<s:property value="#session.loginId" />`.

Comment: I'm trying to display it in jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<s:property value="#session.loginId"/>
```

or

```
${session.loginId}
```

to display session scoped variable value.

Comment: does it `loginId` contains value first? @Desaretius

Comment: yeah, and when I use `<%= session.getAttribute("loginId") %>` it displays fine. Also, I'm using interceptors in this application, maybe it has something to do..

Comment: did you add all the struts 2 required jars to lib folder, but this the solution to print session scoped variable value. @Desaretius

Comment: I think so. It's a maven project in eclipse and I have struts2-core, struts2-taglib and other artifacts in pom.xml file.

Comment: @Satya There's no such scope variable `session` in JSP, but a `sessionScope`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution to this problem. The correct syntax to use when accessing session attributes in struts2 is:

`<s:property value="#session['key']"/>`

[Source](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html)